# How can I have my html table-based-message-board display the newest messages first?

Tags: php, fopen

I made this website message board based in HTML and PHP. It's very annoying having to scroll down to the very bottom every time to view the newest message, so how can I make the newest appear at the top?

In the index.php, a user will put in a desired display name, and message. after they submit it, it will take them to code_exec.php, which sends the variables to the board.html.

This is code_exec.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$nick=htmlspecialchars($_POST['nick']);
$text=htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
$dateTime = date('d/m/y G:i:s');

$data = "<tr>
<td>   $dateTime  </td>
<td>   $nick   </td>
<td>   $text   </td>
</tr>";

$fh = fopen('board.html', 'a');
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "board.html"
</script>';
```

On the board.html it ends up looking like this

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Where is the query which brings the records from database? You need to order by in descending order of date time for post.

Comment: @SaurabhParekh
This is not the problem, the problem is, when you analyze his code, that he append it to a txt file and show only this textfile. There is not database backend .

He did only put data from $_POST into the textfile.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using fopen use file_put_contents and

```
$file_data = $data."\n";
$file_data .= file_get_contents('board.html');
file_put_contents('board.html', $file_data);
```

Comment: Ooh yes this works! except it puts the $data at the very top of the page. I forgot to add that this is the board.html, so the text can't be anywhere. Is there a way to assign it to a certain part of the html? https://hastebin.com/dojadatodu.xml